# How to I simulate these equations. So far I have written code but this gives give me errors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-science

Equations:

$ E_1 = \sum_{j=0}^{J-1} a_j e^{-i(j\Delta+w_o )t}$

$E_2 = e^{-iw_ot} \sum_{m=J}^{J+M} e^{-im\Delta t}(a_m+b_m e^{-iw_ot})$

code:

```
%matplotlib inline


import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.fft import ifft, fftshift

tstart = -10e-9
tstop = 10e-9
delta = 31.6e6 #rep rate
wo = 5e6    #offset frequency
i = 1j


aj = np.array([1 for i in range(500)]) # no of comblines
t = np.linspace (tstart,tstop, 1000)
E1 = np.linspace(0,0,1000).astype("complex") # PSD

for s in range(len(t)):
    for k in range(len(aj)):
        E1[s]+= aj[k]**2*(np.exp(-i*(k*delta+wo)*t[s]))
        
###########################################################

am = np.array([1 for i in range(500)])
bm = np.array([1 for i in range (500)])# no of comblines
t2 = np.linspace (tstart,tstop, 1000)
E2 = np.linspace(0,0,1000, dtype = "complex_") # PSD
m = np.array([i for i in range (500,1000,1)])

for s2 in range(len(t)):
    for k2 in range(len(m)):
        E2[s2]+= (np.exp(-i*wo*t[s2]))*[np.exp(-i*(m[k2]*delta)*t[s2])*(am[k2]+bm[k2]*np.exp(-i*(wo)*t[s2]))]


Then I want to add E1 and E2
```

I am try to simulate two equations.
superposition (addition) of these two equations should give me interference beat signal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a pair of square brackets inappropriately. Look at how you wrote `E2[s2]`: in the middle of it you are essentially creating a list of one element, an array. Removing them fixes the problem:

```
E2[s2]+= (np.exp(-i*wo*t[s2]))*np.exp(-i*(m[k2]*delta)*t[s2])*(am[k2]+bm[k2]*np.exp(-i*(wo)*t[s2]))
```